How to get only absent days in zkteco report
I need to get only absent days in zkteco report. For this purpose I would like to modify any zkteco report in report designer. I think the "Staff's On-Duty/Off-Duty Timetable" report can be modified for this purpose.
If anyone have any idea what code/functions/variables should I put there to get only the date of absent for a particular employee or number of employees for a particular department?
Regards,
Mamun
